# laravel Blade is their a neat solution to : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel-5

I have thins line of code

```
{{($user->company_privileges->level < 3 ? '' : ' disabled') }}
```

In my menu file

but when a user doesn't have a company I get the error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Is their a neat way of dealing with this in one line?

Something like this comes to mind

```
{{ ($user->company_privileges === null) : '' ? ($user->company_privileges->level < 3 ? '' : ' disabled') ) }}
```

as the second if statement is only ran if the user has a company

I have the statement inside a  tag aswell

```
<a class="{{($user->company_privileges->level < 3 ? '' : ' disabled') }}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not something like

```
<a class="{{($user->company_privileges && $user->company_privileges->level < 3 ? '' : ' disabled') }}">
```

Essentially, what you need here is to know that `null == false` for `bool` comparison. Check out the [PHP type comparisons table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)